# How to convert all elements in a list into uppercase using a for loop and upper() while indexing the list directly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python so this is probably super simple.

I'm trying to iterate through a list and convert every element into uppercase. I know that this works:

```
word_list = ['alt', 'mach', 'time']
for i in range(0, len(word_list)):
    word_list[i] = word_list[i].upper()
```

But I also know that you can index a list directly (not using range), but I'm not sure how to apply that to this situation. I tried this:

```
word_list = ['alt', 'mach', 'time']
for i in word_list:
    i = i.upper()
```

But when I print the list afterward it hasn't changed. I suspect this is because i is changing each loop anyway and i can't just assign it to things like I'm trying to do. Is there some other way to do this while indexing the list directly?

Answer (score 5):

Not really. As I think you realise, doing `i = i.upper()` just reassigns `i` to a new string, and doesn't change what's in the list.

The best you can do is to use `enumerate` to give you both the element and the index:

```
for i, word in enumerate(word_list):
    word_list[i] = word.upper()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use list comprehensions. Example:

```
yourList = ["a","b","c"]
yourList = [x.upper() for x in yourList]
```

src: http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html

Answer (score 0):

Super late to the party, but I recommend using the map() function.

```
yourList = ["a","b","c"]
fun = lambda x: x.upper()
yourList = list(map(fun, yourList))
```

Source: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/map.html